# Live video stream issue in Flask

Tags: python, opencv, flask, video-streaming

Hye. I am new to Python and Flask. I am getting live video streaming from camera and displaying it on web interface (FLASK). The server  stays locked to the client until the client disconnects (mean camera is turned off). During video streaming I remain unable to do any other action(mean unable to perform any other action). 
Any solution to get rid from that issue?

PS. I am using OPENCV to capture video.

Comment: Flask is not async. It's hard to give you better advice without the actual minimal code to verify the issue and come up with solution. Perhaps you should look into Celery.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. BTW my code is quite simple, in which I am getting video stream from OPENCV and displaying that in  Iframe (HTML). Actually there is while loop which keeps on getting video stream frame by frame. As the video remain continue, my while loop  remain in action. Which is causing problem.

Comment: As i said. Flask in dev mode is a single synchronous process which means your app will have to finish previous action before starting another. Since your code is blocking (while loop) it wont let you do anything else until loop exits. Your only option here is use something like celery worker which would execute your loop in another process while passing callbacks to your main thread (flask app). Celery is great for creating microservices with flask.

Comment: You can also try to use sleep in your while loop to hand back the thread execution to the main thread but your video might not be as smooth. Didn't test this so not sure if this would work at all.